# Can not join two vertices

Tags: vertices, edges

I'm a very beginner in Blender. I'm trying to connect two vertices laying on the same plane (these edges were a part of a face that I deleted earlier):

[image]

But when I select them and press <kbd>J</kbd> it shows the `Could not connect vertices` error. How to solve it? What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Hello :). To create new edges go *Vertex > New face/edge/vertex* (shortcut: **F**). **J** only works to connect vertices across an existing face.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

<kbd>J</kbd> only works on faces that already exist, it's basically a shortcut to cut a face between vertices (like the knife tool but just for cutting a face between vertices with a single button press)
You want the <kbd>F</kbd> key for this one. It will "fill" an edge between the 2 vertices.
If you want to make a face from 3 or more vertices, select the vertices and hit <kbd>F</kbd> to make a face.

<kbd>F</kbd> can be used in many different situations, like simply selecting a single edge that has other edges connected to it and boom, instant face. Try it out!

Comment: I wouldn't say _J_ is a shortcut for the _Knife Tool_. First of all it's the shortcut for _Connect Vertex Path_, which means you have to select vertices to use it. Second, the _Knife Tool_ has its own shortcut _K_ and is capable of cutting faces and edges everywhere without the need to select vertices (although cuts can be snapped to vertices). That's a very different tool.

Comment: I didn't mean a keyboard shortcut, just an easier way to cut a face quickly between 2 verts, I'll update the answer

Comment: Yes, I think it's better now, otherwise it might confuse users that are new to Blender.